# C# regex: replace either of two matches with the same value

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to do some regex matching and replacement in a string, whereby all ampersand, single quote, and space characters are replaced with dashes "-"

...and

all repeating dashes are replaced with a single dash.

This is what I'm trying but it's not working, in that the repeating dashes aren't being substituted.  Any help is appreciated and thanks.

```
Regex.Replace(mystring, "([' &])|([-]{2,})", "-")
```

Comment: It might be better to say, "ampersand, single quote, and space characters" than "&" "'".  The latter is very difficult to read.

Comment: Can we get a sample of a string that's not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one (seems more simple). I'm assuming you never want "--" in the result.

```
string orig = "12467&89- 1&2467'89 12'46789 12467--89";

Regex regex = new Regex("[&' -]+");

string newString = regex.Replace(orig, "-");
```

output:

```
12467-89-1-2467-89-12-46789-12467-8
```

Answer (score 1):

That regular expression should work:

You just need to do the assignment:

```
mystring = Regex.Replace(mystring, "([' &])|([-]{2,})", "-");
```

Strings are immutable, remember?

Comment: Thanks Michael.  If I make this call as an example I still get two dashes in a row:  string mystring = Regex.Replace("hi&--6-", "([' &])|([-]{2,})", "-");

Comment: Yes because your regular expression does not group ampersands and single quotes with hyphens.  If your intention is for your resulting string to have no double hyphens, then use the regex in James' answer.